# Slideshow with changing img src attribute

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I want to create a simple slide show by changing `src` attribute of image (id=`imgT`).
`ultop` is not visible (`display:none`)

```
<img id='imgT' src="top/00.jpg">
<ul id="ultop">
   <li><img src="top/00.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="top/01.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="top/02.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="top/03.jpg"></li>
</ul>

<script>
n=0;
x=$('#ultop li').length;

setInterval(function() { 
    if ( n < (x - 1)){n+=1;}
    else {n=0};
    var goimg = $('#ultop li img' + ':eq(' + n +')').attr('src');
    $('#imgT').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('#imgT').attr('src', goimg).fadeIn();
});
},  7000)
</script>
```

But, there is a blank gap between fadeOut and fadeIn.
You can see live example [here](http://bonaca.net46.net/)

Is there a way to make this process smoothly without that blank gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('#imgT').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('#imgT').attr('src', goimg).fadeIn();
});
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Anil, it helps partially. `src` attribute is changed on time, but there is still blank gap between `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`.

Comment: you can make the fadeout action to be fast,`$('#imgT').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('#imgT').attr('src', goimg).fadeIn('fast');
});`